# REGEX to manipulate variable assignments in strings

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need a regex for my PHP script that will help me manipulate some strings using `preg_replace`.

For example, say I have the following string:

```
myvar = first_value AND var2 = second_value
```

I would like to have it converted to:

```
myvar = 'first_value' AND var2 = 'second_value'
```

However, I would also like to have it ignore when there is already a single quote around the value. So `myvar = first_value AND var2 = 'second_value'` will become `myvar = 'first_value' AND var2 = 'second_value'` and not `myvar = 'first_value' AND var2 = ''second_value''`.

I would also like it to deal with spaces within sub-strings when there is already a single quote around the value. So `myvar = first_value AND var2 = 'second value'` will become `myvar = 'first_value' AND var2 = 'second value'` and not `myvar = 'first_value' AND var2 = 'second' value'`.

NOTE: At no time will the string contain variable assignment with unquoted string values that have spaces in them i.e. `myvar = first value` is a scenario that will never arise. However, the string can contain any other character, even special characters e.g. `myvar = &%$@_imspecial_*` is totally valid.

The PHP Code I was working with looked something like below (#DontLaugh):

```
$col_clause_str = "myvar = first_value AND var2 = second_value";
$replace_pattern_str = '/([\w\@\-]+)\s*(\=|\>|\>\=|\<|\<\=)\s*\'{0,1}([\w\@\.\:\+\-\/\|\{\}\[\]\~\%\$\*\!]+)\'{0,1}/i';
$replace_str = '\1 \2 \'\3\'';
$col_clause_str = preg_replace($replace_pattern_str, $replace_str, $col_clause_str);
```

How can I improve this Regex?!

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I updated the question to be more descriptive.

Comment: `"That's the thing about strings," he said, "you wouldn't believe all of the stuff you can include in them; not only letters, but special symbols such as ({}!=, etc!"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace this regex: -

```
"/(?<==\s)(\w+)/i"
```

with: -

```
'\1'
```

---

**Update: -**

Ok, for your updated question, you can use this regex: -

```
"/(?<==\s)([^\s']+)/i"
```

And replace it with same string - `'\1'`

Comment: @mellamokb I think he only wants to "stringize" the variable assignations. And that works perfectly.

Comment: @Chuck.. Ok, I updated the answer. Check if it covers all your possibilities.

Comment: @Rohit No, it doesn't work. Here's what I did and you can try it yourself: `$col_clause_str = "myvar = first_value AND var2 = second_value"; $replace_pattern_str = '/(?<==\s)([^\s\']+)/i';
   $replace_str = '\1';
   $col_clause_str = preg_replace($replace_pattern_str, $replace_str, $col_clause_str);`

Comment: Ok, and what did you got and what did you expect? I have tried that and it works in Java. And it should certainly work with `preg_replace`.

Comment: @Rohit Well, I'm not using Java...I'm using PHP as my question describes.

Comment: @ChuckUgwuh. Yeah, that I understand. But it would also work in `preg_replace`. What did you got the output, when you tried it?

Comment: @ChuckUgwuh.. Ok, there seems to be some problem. Let me correct it.

Comment: @ChuckUgwuh.. No, it works fine according to your requirement. I tested it on http://www.functions-online.com/preg_replace.html

Comment: See this: -  http://regex-test.com/share-url.php?url=validate/php/preg_replace&vp=%2F(%3F%3C%3D%3D%5Cs)(%5B%5E%5Cs'%5D%2B)%2Fi&vs=myvar%20%3D%20first_value%20AND%20var2%20%3D%20second_value&vr='%5C1'&vc=In%20this%20sentence%20I%20was%20replaced.

Comment: @Rohit Ok, I had to make a few edits in my code before I could get it to work, but it's working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with PHP and its regular expression capabilities, but maybe this Python code helps you a bit:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: str1 = "myvar = first_value AND var2 = second_value"

In [3]: str2 = "myvar = first_value AND var2 = 'second_value'"

In [4]: str3 = "myvar = 'first value' AND var2 = second_value"

In [5]: regex = r"""
 .....:     (?P<variable_name>
 .....:         \w+
 .....:         \s*
 .....:         =
 .....:         \s*
 .....:     )
 .....:     (?<! ' )     # negative look-behind assertion
 .....:     (?P<value>
 .....:         \w+
 .....:     )
 .....:     (?! ' )      # negative look-ahead assertion
 .....:     """

In [6]: replacement = "\g<variable_name>'\g<value>'"

In [7]: re.sub(regex, replacement, str1, flags=re.X)
Out[7]: "myvar = 'first_value' AND var2 = 'second_value'"

In [8]: re.sub(regex, replacement, str2, flags=re.X)
Out[8]: "myvar = 'first_value' AND var2 = 'second_value'"

In [9]: re.sub(regex, replacement, str3, flags=re.X)
Out[9]: "myvar = 'first value' AND var2 = 'second_value'"
```

You probably have to adjust `\w+` to fit all characters than can be possible in your variable names. The idea here is to use negative look-behind and look-ahead assertions to check whether a variable value is already surrounded by quotes.